# How to check if 'select' has some options?

Tags: php, testing, selenium, phpunit

I am writing test script using **Selenium** & **PHPUnit**. 
I have got a form containing drop-down lists. I have to verify if data is read from database and presented as options in the 'select' elements. 
When there is no options in the select, the code is:

```
<select id="list">

</select>
```

Method `assertNotEmpty("list")` doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`if (document.getElementById('list').innerHTML !== "")

//do something` - might not work in explorer.

Comment: Thanks, pinkypower. I can do it with js, of course. But at first I want to know how to do it only with Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of options using `selectOptionValues()` function.

```
$optionValues = $this->select($this->byName('name_of_dropdown'))->selectOptionValues();
$this->assertGreaterThan(0, count($optionValues));
```

Hope this will help to resolve your issue.